# Magento add charge to orders over $999

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone point out how someone would achieve a surcharge (percentage) on orders over a certain threshold in Magento.

In Drupal I would use rules to trigger a tax % added to the subtotal of the order and only if the order is over a threshold (condition).

Are there any such core modules in Magento ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You will simply need to create pricing rules. Magento Community and Enterprise editions both include this core ability.

The catalog price rule management interface is found in the shop administration backend under `Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules`.

[Here](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-catalog-price-rules/) is an article that explains it very well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the subtotal of the order, then the Shopping Cart pricing rule can add this condition.

Shopping cart price ruled uses conditions per order, while catalog price rules uses condition per product.

However, it will be added as discount and not tax.

Answer (score 2):

Go through this tutorial http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/ 
I have used this tutorial as basis when I was creating similar extension.